# Posting drupal content to tumblr

Tags: nodes

I am trying to post article content type to my tumblr account (want to post all articles created by different user roles) . I have tried [tumblr_connect](https://www.drupal.org/project/tumblr_connect) but its not working i have also installed [tumblr api](https://www.drupal.org/project/tumblr) module and registered a application and added the keys.

But i am stuck there i dont how to configure to post only the article content type and link it to my tumblr blog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to do this in code. Use hook_node_insert() in a custom module and filter by content type. You can then invoke the tumblr API and send the node data across. See tumblr.lib.php for API usage.